# How to manipulate two csv flowfiles in ExecuteScript using Python?

Tags: python, csv, apache-nifi

In my flow, I query Hive, then update the file names, and then I want to combine these csvs into one excel workbook with multiple spreadsheets. I was able to make the two csv files merge into one excel workbook with multiple spreadsheets using this code. How do I get the script to use the two files from the nifi flow instead of pulling the files from a directory on my pc? I've seen that can do "flowFile = session.get()" but does this line capture both flowfiles?

```
import glob
import csv
import xlwt
import os
import xlsxwriter
import datetime
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook("combined_at%s.xlsx" %             datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S'))

flowFile = session.get()

replacer = ",[]\"\"'\'"
worksheet = wb.add_worksheet("make")
worksheet2 = wb.add_worksheet("ownership")
worksheet3 = wb.add_worksheet("marital")
worksheet4 = wb.add_worksheet("drivers")
worksheet5 = wb.add_worksheet("vehicles")
worksheet6 = wb.add_worksheet("age")
worksheet7 = wb.add_worksheet("vyear")

def printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet, index):
    for y in replacer:
        split_row[0] = split_row[0].replace(y, "")
    worksheet.write(index, 0, split_row[0])
    return;

def printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet,index,non_changing_index):
    for y in replacer:
        split_row[non_changing_index] = split_row[non_changing_index].replace(y, "")
    worksheet.write(index, 1, split_row[non_changing_index])
    return;

with open("1.csv") as csv1:
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for row in csv1:
        split_row = row.split(",")
        if split_row[2] != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet, i)
            printOtherOnes(split_row,worksheet,i,2)
            i = i+1
        if split_row[3].strip() != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet2, j)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet2, j, 3)
            j = j+1


with open("2.csv") as csv1:
    i = 0; k = 0; j = 0; l = 0;m = 0;
    for row in csv1:
        split_row = row.split(",")
        if split_row[2] != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet3, i)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet3, i, 2)
            i = i + 1
        if split_row[3].strip() != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet4, j)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet4, j, 3)
            j = j + 1
        if split_row[5] != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet5, l)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet5, l, 5)
            l = l + 1
        if split_row[4].strip() != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row, worksheet6, k)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet6, k, 4)
            k = k + 1
        if split_row[6].strip() != "":
            printHashedEmail(split_row,worksheet7,m)
            printOtherOnes(split_row, worksheet7, m, 6)
            m = m + 1

wb.close()

print("Done")
```

[Here is the Nifi FLow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwrMR.png)

After manipulation, I would like the excel file to exit the ExecuteScriptProcessor so I can do more with it

Answer (score 2):

check different [`session.get()` methods](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.6.0/index.html?org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html).

for example `session.get(2)` will try get 2 first files from incoming queue.

if you got only one you can call `session.rollback()` to return it back to queue.

but the problem here that files in queue could be in different order then you expected. just imagine you have 3 files in the incoming queue.

with `session.get(FlowFileFilter filter)` you can select from incoming queue 2 files that matched by some attribute.

Comment: The hive queries will run once a month so there will only be 0-2 flow files in queue at a time.  How could I assign the flow files to a variable like my "csv1" and "csv2" files?

Comment: i'm not a master of jython. but according to internet: `session.read(flowFile)` returns java input stream for the flowFile. and [FileUtil.wrap(stream)](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/util/FileUtil.html) converts stream to PyFile object. so this kind of expression should help you: `csv1 = FileUtil.wrap( session.read(flowFile1) )`